# Hough transform R PET package detecting a line

Tags: r, hough-transform

I have image as below and i want to detect the line in the image using PET package's hough tranform. I need help to understand how to get the line from that image.

```
library("PET", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("raster", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")

p=matrix(diag(100), 100)
library(raster)
r <- raster(p)
plot(r)
abc=hough(p)

viewData(list(p, abc$hData), list("Phantom", "Hough transformed phantom"))
```

I applied hough transformation as above. The original image and image that i get after running the last line are as below[image][image]

any inputs on how to get line's coordinates (from original image)? I understand that white point from the second image right side pane represents the line. That line is plotted using Polar Cordinate system. But i dont know how to use the second image to get coordinate of the original line

I looked at PET package's documentation but found it hard to understand :( I ran their sample code but i didn't understand it

==============================================================================

I followed advice given in comments by user NicE and updated my code as below

```
library("PET", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("raster", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")

#p=matrix(diag(1000), 1000)
p=matrix(rep(0,10000), 100, 100)
# for (i in 1:100)
# {p[i,100-i+1]=1
# }
for (i in 1:100)
{p[i,50]=1
}


# library(raster)
# r <- raster(p)
# plot(r)
abc=hough(p)

maxPoint<-which(abc$hData==max(abc$hData),arr.ind=T)
library(pracma)
a<-cot(maxPoint[1,"row"]*pi/180)
b<-maxPoint[1,"col"]/sin(maxPoint[1,"row"]*pi/180)
a
b
par(pty="s")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
#image(r, main="org")
image(p,main="original")
image(abc$hData, main="Houghmatrix")
```

Are new values of a and b correct? I feel that b should be 50 (perpendicular distance of the original line from the (0,0)). What am I doing wrong?

I would also like to know why does abc$hData has 181 rows and 143 columns. I can imagine 181 rows has something to do with PI radians is 180 degrees. But I dont have any clue about 143 columns...

=======================================================================
update 2
If i update my original matrix as I feel that i get weird answers. I get a=-57.6 and b=1786.12.

```
p=matrix(rep(0,10000), 100, 100)

for (i in 1:100)
{p[80,i]=1
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any samples where they were processing R matrix objects. Why don't you try using the package's read-facilities for image formats.

Comment: I looked into PET package documentation and looked at page 4/hough part. It says that the input parameter oData (matrix) is A matrix that contains the image (for the Hough transformation).

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the Hough transformation of the data, find the indices of the max of the matrix (assuming you have only one line):

`maxPoint<-which(abc$hData==max(abc$hData),arr.ind=T)`

You can also take the average of all the maxPoitns if you know there is only one line. In your case, you get this:

```
    row col
[1,] 137  72
```

You need the default parameters of the function as well

houghParam<-unlist(abc$Header)

These give you RhoMin, ThethaMin, and DeltaMin and DeltaRho, the increments of both variables. With these you can get rho and theta from the matrix coordinates.

```
theta=(maxPoint[1,"row"]-1)*houghParam["DeltaXY1"]+houghParam["XYmin1"]
rho=(maxPoint[1,"col"]-1)*houghParam["DeltaXY2"]+houghParam["XYmin2"]
```

If the equation of the line is `y=ax+b`, you can get `a` and `b` using:

```
library(pracma)
a<--cot(theta)
b<-(rho)/sin(theta)
```

Also, in the man page of `hough` they state that they take the center of the image as (0,0) points.

For the math explanation, look at the [Wikipedia page of Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) ...

Edit: changed a formula and removed some wrong info

The total code would be:

```
library(PET)
library(pracma)

a=matrix(rep(0,10000), 100, 100)
for (i in 1:100)
{a[i,60]=1
}

d=matrix(rep(0,10000), 100, 100)
for (i in 1:100)
{d[60,i]=1
}

e=matrix(diag(100), 100)

getLineHough<-function(p){
abc=hough(p)
#get the brightest point in the hough tranform
maxPoint<-which(abc$hData==max(abc$hData),arr.ind=T)
#if there is only one line, can average the results in case there are several brightest points
maxPoint<-apply(maxPoint,2,mean)

houghParam<-unlist(abc$Header)

theta=(maxPoint[1]-1)*houghParam["DeltaXY1"]+houghParam["XYmin1"]
rho=(maxPoint[2]-1)*houghParam["DeltaXY2"]+houghParam["XYmin2"]

a<--cot(theta)
b<-rho/sin(theta)


par(mfrow=c(1,2))
image(p,main="original")
#add the predicted lines, also have to change the slope and intercept because
#the origin of the plot function is not the center of the image the bottom left corner
if(theta==0){
        abline(v=(rho+50)/100)
} else{
        abline((b+50-a*50)/100,a)
}
image(abc$hData, main="Houghmatrix")
}

getLineHough(a)
getLineHough(d)
getLineHough(e)
```

Edit2: the documentation doesn't really say what the value of the first row of the matrix is. Since there are 181 rows it should start at 0 and not 1*houghParam["DeltaXY1"]. Changed the code accordingly

Edit3: made the code into a function and added the predicted line to the plot

Comment: I am rewarding you bounty because I feel that you have done a lot of work and your answer seems to be correct. But let me check further and I will let you know if I have more questions

Comment: i feel that something is still missing. Please answer my update2

Comment: changed the code, index should start at 0 and not 1, for a vertical line you can't get an equation like y=ax+b, but the rho and theta parameters are correct

Comment: also there are 143 columns in the hData because from the center of the image, the distance to the corner is `100*sqrt(2)/2~71` (in this case). Since it can be minus and plus and the rho values is changed one by one,  you need 2*71+1 rows. (you can also check parameter RhoSamples)

Comment: Thanks. In case of simple images like the above, I was expecting that the package would return accurate results. Any idea why results are a bit off?

Comment: One more thing, how can i get starting and ending point of the line. Let's say the line goes from (1,0) to (0.5, 0.5) then I am getting the exactly same values for a and b. It would be super helpful if i can get start and the end point

Comment: Changed the code to plot the predicted line in the first graph and to take the mean of max points (only good if you only have one line). When you run it on your example you can see the prediction is pretty much perfect. Not sure you can get start and end points with this function.

Comment: Changed the code, now it plots the predicted line on the first plot. As you see for your three examples it's pretty much perfect

Comment: Also, using max to get the brightest points is very crude (if there are two lines it might not work), you might want to look around to find functions that give you local maxima or some sort of peak calling to be able to detect two or more lines.

Comment: There is small typo with your code. Please change the third line from the last to getLineHough(a)

Comment: Also would it be possible to upvote my question? I have 2 negative ratings on my question. But since then i have added more information to my code and also added a working example.

Comment: I feel that your answers would be helpful to others and it would be better if other users dont get scared away by 2 negative ratings